# React App can't read Kubernetes env variables

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes

i'm using Kubernetes Deployment to deploy a React App, so,this is my deployment.yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: bits-deployment-frontend
  namespace: bits
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: reactapp
          image: xgiovanni/bits-frontend:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          env:
            - name: REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL
              value: backend-service
            - name: REACT_APP_BACKEND_PORT
              value: "8081"
```

And the code where i'm using the env variables is this: (I have to say, i'm using the react-dotenv lib to catch this variables but the `env` var is getting a undefined, tell me for any missing information

```
import axios from 'axios'
import env from 'react-dotenv';

//export const LOGIN = 'realms/keycloak-react-auth/protocol/openid-connect/token'
export const LOGIN = 'login'
export const REGISTER = 'users'
export const SESSIONS = 'sessions'
export const BLOBS = 'blobs'
export const SESSIONS_NAME = 'sessions/search'


export class CRUDService {

    //static baseURL = 'http://' + env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + ':' + env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_PORT + '/'
    static baseURL = "";
    static post(postInformation, serviceRoute) {

        var url = this.baseURL + serviceRoute

        return axios.post(url, postInformation.data, postInformation.headers)
            .then(res => res)
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(url);
                console.log(env);
                if (error.response) {
                    // Request made and server responded
                    alert("ERROR " + error.response.data.code + "\n" + error.response.data.message);

                } else if (error.request) {
                    // The request was made but no response was received
                    console.log(error.request);
                } else {
                    // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
                    console.log('Error', error.message);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: React runs in the browser, the environment variable only exists in the backend. React App created with create-react-app script can only read environment variables at build time. Unless you use the development server for production which, I must say, is not recommended.